# can i scale down azure hdinsight cluster?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

i have created azure hdinsight with 8 node cluster. i am running hive query which occupies all the worker nodes.
when i check yarn node -list, the following is listed:

```
Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       No-of-Running-Containers
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 8
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 8
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 8
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 8
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 8
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 8
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 8
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 8
```

after some hours, mapper has been completed and 2 reducers are running, like below:

```
Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       No-of-Running-Containers
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 0
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 1
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 0
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 0
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 1
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 0
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 0
X.X.X.X:00050        RUNNING X.X.X.X:00060                 0
```

when arriving at this stage, can we be able to scale down the cluster which does not affect the running 2 worker nodes?

Comment: Did you check which HDFS DataNodes the reducers were reading/writing to? Did you read about what "decommissioning" a DataNode implies, in terms of rebalancing the file blocks so that each one is still replicated 3 times?

Comment: In other words, Hadoop is not only a distributed computing framework, it is a distributed **filesystem**. It moves data around. Would you just rip the hard disk out of your laptop while it is running...?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I haven't tried to scale a running HDInsight cluster, but I have read an official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-administer-use-powershell) on the supported cluster scaling operations (while jobs are running). The supported applications are:

- Hadoop
- Hbase
- Spark

You probably should not scale with Hive queries running because (1) Hive is not in the list, and (2) the document described what happens to Hadoop jobs if you scale down with jobs running as below. IMHO this may happen to Hive jobs too.

> When a Hadoop cluster is scaled down by reducing the number of data
>   nodes, some of the services in the cluster are restarted. This causes
>   all running and pending jobs to fail at the completion of the scaling
>   operation. You can, however, resubmit the jobs once the operation is
>   complete.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are two type of  auto scaling possible with HDInsights cluster which you can manage from azure portal - 
1.) Schedule base. - like as per given schedule (8PM - 5AM- only 2 nodes)
2.) Load base - remove nodes if unused for 30 mins or so.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-autoscale-clusters

I think you can use Load based auto scaling for your case.